# Running from server.js example from nodebeginner book on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am new to node.js and Heroku.  I have tried to run the very first example server.js from the nodebeginner book on Heroku.  The code for server.js is

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

To deploy server.js on Heroku, I have modified the files provided on 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs

Especially, I have changed the file package.json to

```
{
    {
        "name": "node-example",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "dependencies": {
        "http": "0.10.x"      <=== changed this line 
    },
        "engines": {
        "node": "0.10.x",
        "npm": "1.2.x"
    }
}
```

However, when I run npm install the error message

```
npm WARN package.json node-example@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json node-example@0.0.1 No readme data.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/http
npm ERR! 404 'http' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-40-virtual
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/nodebeginner
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.32
npm ERR! code E404
```

So, how should I install the package "http" http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http
so I can use it on Heroku?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the `http` dependency to your `package.json` file---it is already part of node.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I removed the http dependency in package.json, I could push server.js to Heroku and did not get a compilation error anymore.

Comment: Great! There are other modules in Node Core that you do not need to add to your `package.json`: http://nodejs.org/api/index.html. By the way, if that solved your problem, the custom is to mark this as the right answer ;-).